# Syncing taxonomy between Drupal <-> 3rd-party system?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a custom made system (non Drupal) that has a taxonomy like:

```
Element 1
   Element 1.1
   Element 1.2
   Element 1.3
Element 2
   Element 2.1
   Element 2.2
Element 3
   ...
```

And I have a Drupal site that would like to be able to:

1. Use this taxonomy for tagging content, and
2. Add more terms that the non-Drupal system can use too.

Is there a popular way to ***sync*** a taxonomy in a Drupal system with an external system?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a simple thing to do. You would need to have some exposed interface from which Drupal can read the taxonomy from the other system.

Assuming there is an exposed api to pull the Taxonomy terms in from, I would use the [Migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) that run every cron to sync the terms from one to another. How you build this with Migrate depends entirely on how you can connect to the external system; could be sql, xml, json, csv ...

You will also have to think about a few issues with having a system like this.

- What happens when a term is deleted from the other system?
- What happens when a term is deleted from Drupal?
- What happens when a term is added to Drupal that doesn't exist in the external system?
- What happens when a term is added to Drupal that does exist in the external system?